# How do I plant seeds in Terraria mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I need to plant seeds (Mushroom grass, jungle grass, etc...) for the Truffle and for farming. I tried placing down 3x3 dirt, and clicking-holding on all the blocks. That didn't work. How do I plant seeds so I can get the Truffle??

Comment: IIRC mushroom grass seeds can only be planted on mud. I haven't played the mobile version, but on the PC you use seeds like any other item. If you are using them on a tile that they aren't compatible with, they won't be planted.

Comment: @Adeese Thankyouverymuch! I didn't realize you could only plant seeds in mud. That would explain why I could never plant anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to plant mushroom grass, it must be planted in mud, not dirt. This is likely why you couldn't plant it. I believe that jungle grass can also only be planted in mud.